# Extension for VS Code that evaluates math expressions?

Tags: text-editor, programming, math, visual-studio-code

I am looking for an extension for Visual Studio Code that can evaluate simple math expressions to save time. Sometimes I fiddle around with numbers, and add constants to expressions to save time so I don't have to bring out a calculator and figure out the constants.

I'm thinking something along the lines of pressing a hotkey while text is selected.

Comment: Personally, I would run the code in the debugger and evaluate various expression there